# iAd strange message - iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, iad

I have enabled iAd for an app of mine and I have submitted it to Apple a few moments ago.

Meanwhile, I see this message on iAd for the app **Testing: This app is receiving test ads. This app's status is not yet Ready For Sale. You have not configured ad preferences for this app.**

I have not configured ad preferences? What ad preferences? I just see a button ENABLE/DISABLE on iTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few 'preferences'.

"Age of target audience is under 17" and "disable ads with specific keywords" are the only two I can think of though.

You won't see proper ads when you are testing though, you'll only get those when your app is live.

Comment: ok, but should I worry of my app going live and continue to serve test ads or will this message vanish when the app goes live? I have not created any filter for the ads and my audience is not under 17.

Comment: You don't need to create any filters if you don't want to filter anything and your audience doesn't have to be under 17, they just ask once when you click Enable.
I can't think of anything you have missed to get real ads when your app goes live unless there is something on the App Information page to enable.

Comment: ok. Thanks. But lately I am having a lot of problems with Apple accounts on iTC and iAd Network. Every time I have to wait weeks until they solve the stuff. I hope this goes without problems when the app goes live. Thanks.

Comment: Have a check over all of the settings on your app on itc incase i missed anything.

Comment: as you said, there's not much to set there. Just two items and they were set.